# @font-face won't work. how do I do this properly?

Tags: html, css

So I have this custom font and it won't work. Please help.

```
@font-face{
  font-family: Anton;
  src: url('../../assets/fonts/Anton-Regular.ttf')format('truetype');
}

.home-content-right h1{
font-size: 60px;
font-style: 'Anton',sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: do you add font-face at the begining of stylesheet? also, use this @font-face{
  font-family: 'Anton';
  src: url('../../assets/fonts/Anton-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}

Comment: and make sure, that you defined right url for fonts

Answer (score 0):

```
 @font-face {
 font-family: myFont;
 src: url(fonts/Akrobat-Bold.otf);
 }

 .h1{
 font-family: "myFont";
    }
```

For example, I put .otf font file in folder fonts, that works without problem. You will just change name of your font and source  path.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things could be happening. 
First, your h1 tag is using font-style instead of font, so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Anton;
  src: url('../../assets/fonts/Anton-Regular.ttf')format('truetype');
}

.home-content-right h1{
  font: 'Anton',sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

i.e. font rather than font-style on the h1.

Also, it looks like its possible you are using Rails or some other framework based on the folder structure you are using. If so, its possible that the framework is digesting your asset (i.e. fingerprinting it so its             Anton-Regular.ttf-02987910hsa or something like that in case it changes so your browser doesn't cache it incorrectly. If you are using Rails, you'll need to use asset-url('URL') in order to get the most recently fingerprinted asset.